# Как правильно настроить создание бекапов всей системы?

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование

Хочу научится делать бекапы и восстановление системы правильно.

Надо ссылка на статью или методичку или курс или инструкцию, проработав которую я
мог бы с уверенностью сказать что умею решать почти все задачи связанные с бекапами.

Хочу понять принципы построения бекапов.
Спасибо!

Comment: man dump содержит несколько очень полезных хинтов, например.

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Пробовали поискать что-то перед заданием вопроса?

Comment: Читай исходные коды bacula.

Comment: `BorgBackup` посмотри.